# add ll alias In Ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

How I can add `ll` alias to `ls -l` command.

I can not find `.bashrc` file in my home.
I tried to add into `.bashrc.user` file, but it does not work.

Comment: something's not right if you don't have `.bashrc`. What's your setup and environment?

Answer (score 11):

The package `bash` is installed by default on every Ubuntu version and flavour and contains the file `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, which is copied into every new user's home directory, so you should definitely have a file `~/.bashrc`. If you accidentally removed it you can restore it by copying it again:

```bsh
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

The file already by default contains these lines:

```bsh
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Your `alias` is available when you source the `bashrc` with `. ~/.bashrc` or just open a new session.

Answer (score 1):

If the `.bashrc` file doesn't exist, you can create it in your home :

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

then you can add your alias inside :

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

But as Zanna is suggesting, this is not normal if you don't have this file

Comment: `ll` is actually a default Ubuntu alias btw: `grep 'alias ll=' .bashrc` output: `alias ll='ls -alF'`

Answer (score 0):

You can create .bashrc file in your home directory.
$vim ~/.bashrc 
$alias ll="ls -l"
:wq
To bring all modification in effect run following command
$source .bashrc
To see all alias you created run following command
$alias